# why is the rest api call not working?

Tags: javascript, api, http

I am trying to fetch data by making an api call however the browser keeps showing xhr failed loading.  i cant understand the mistake in my code.

```
function letsgo()
{
   var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ourRequest.open('GET','https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=083f90f14c7d4a8b8346a5f944dedd58',true);

  ourRequest.onload = function()
  {
    if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) 
    {

      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      renderHTML(ourData);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
    }

  };

  ourRequest.onerror = function() {
      console.log("Connection error");
  };

  ourRequest.send(); 
}
```

below is the function which logs the data

```
 function renderHTML(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
```

Comment: The code is working fine. Something linked to your network/proxy/firewall/... Can you access the url from your browser ?

Comment: Agreed, this fiddle works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/msfwjmpk/ Does it produce an error for you?

Comment: yes. there is no problems with url loading.

Comment: Try to log the error : `ourRequest.onerror = function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }`

Comment: no error is being thrown. it just shows XHR failed loading: GET "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=083f90f14c7d4a8b8346a5f944dedd58".
letsgo @ /C:/Users/user/Desktop/JS%20testing/js/hello.js:15

Comment: @batman007 The issue is that you're viewing the page as a `file://` page, which is never allowed cross-origin access to resources on other origins, even when those other resources are served with correct CORS headers. You need to access the page through a web server as an `http:` or `https:` page

Comment: @apsillers i am not sure on how to do that. can u tell me the changes i need to make?

Comment: figured it out .chrome was out of date. i just updated it and everything is working smooth . just has me wondering why an out of date chrome didnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample Code. This Codes works fine.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function renderHTML(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

        function letsgo() {
            var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ourRequest.open('GET',
                'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?
source=techcrunch&apiKey=083f90f14c7d4a8b8346a5f944dedd58',
                true);

            ourRequest.onload = function () {
                if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {

                    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
                    renderHTML(ourData);
                } else {
                    console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned 
an error.");
                }

            };

            ourRequest.onerror = function () {
                console.log("Connection error");
            };

            ourRequest.send();
        }

        letsgo();
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method of fetching data is a bit old, recently all major browsers are supporting `fetch` api

You can use it like:

```js
fetch('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=083f90f14c7d4a8b8346a5f944dedd58')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => {
    document.getElementById("root").innerText = JSON.stringify(data, 0, 2)
  })
```

```html
<pre id="root">
</pre>
```

Comment: your code snippet is working fine however it just fails to run on my browser.i guess there is some problem with my browser.it shows the same thing when i am logging the data

Comment: mine and your code now runs perfectly . my browser was just out of date.